# Where are all the multiterminal discrete transistors?

Tags: transistors, components

Looking at all the various schematics of op amps, regulators, etc. I see lots of multicollector or multiemitter BJTs (and why no multibase?). How come these (or their MOSFET equivalents) aren't seen in discrete form? Is there a practical reason beyond "no one wants them"?

**EDIT:**

An example of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: Is there any practical difference between that drawing and just a normal BJT where there are three connections soldered to the emitter?

Comment: @medivh: yes, definitely. For one thing, no current can flow between E1 and E2 because one of the BE diodes will always be blocking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The picture you show is probably from a TTL-style AND gate, where the multi-emitter transistor was used to function as a bunch of diodes (each from B to En), where each emitter could be used to pull the base connector low, thus implementing the AND function.

The reason this was preferred over separate diodes is that a multi-emitter transistor takes up less space on a chip than the corresponding set of diodes. And once you have such multi-emitter transistors on a chip, nicely integrated in a complete AND port, why would you want to build an (inferior) AND port yourself from its components? (If you wanted to do so, using separate diodes would be easier because they are small and cheap.)

A totally different use of muti-emitters is current splitting. With careful manufacturing a transistor can be made so that the current on one emitter is always a fixed part (let's say 0.01) of the current of the other emitter. This is used in OpAmps to create current sources, and in low-drop voltage regulators to implement overcurrent protection without a sense resistor in series with the main current (which would add to the dropout voltage). Again, no separate multi-emitters of this kind are (widely?) available because no-one wants to build something from scratch that is available better and cheaper in one package.

Comment: Good answer. However, the bit about a multi-emitter transistor being equivalent to a bunch of diodes is not quite correct. In a TTL-NAND, the transistor saturates when at least one input is low, resulting in a voltage drop of around 0.1V from input pin to the following stage, in contrast to 0.7V if you use a silicon diode for each input pin. The logic functions is identical to the diodes of course, as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because they don't save on pin count or size? That said, I found BCR198S Two independent pnp transistors + builtin bias resistors in SOT363.

And further googling shows that the terms "Dual transistor" and "transistor array" shows a bunch, with independent transistors. CA3083, LM3046, BC847BS, BRC22PN, SSM-2220P, 2N6987, etc.

[Digikey Dynamic Catalog, 9 different manufacturers of NPN/PNP Arrays.](http://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/search?filters=16363)

[2500 results for pre-biased BJT arrays](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-bjt-arrays-pre-biased/1377267)

[1900 results for non-biased BJT arrays](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-bjt-arrays/1376378)

These exist, I've never seen them, but they exist.

Comment: These are arrays of multiple transistors. I'm asking about transistors with multiple terminals of a single type, e.g. [this](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Multiemitter_Transistor.svg).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams oh, then the question is kinda vague, you might want to add that picture to it. I thought you were talking about things like ULN2803, where the emitter is all tied together.